# How to get a notification when windows prompt a dialog (i.e. error message)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, winapi

**the situation:**

a user tries to copy a file to a directory he doesn't have write permission in, 
he will be prompted with a dialog box.

**The requirement:**

In a separate unrelated process, I want to get notified when this happens.

**Possible solution paths:**

1. subscribe to a system event if one exists.
2. using hooks

Is this even possible? 
which of the two is the preferred path?

a code example doing this would be a life saver...

Comment: There is something else called access violation, I think you talk about access denied

Comment: I doubt you'll get a hook here since there's no obvious reason why any app would need one

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I want to be able to automatically close those prompt dialogs (identifying them is the first step)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()` to receive notifications when a window is created and about to receive focus. You can then analyze the window contents to see if it matches what you are looking for and act accordingly.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach  - How should I analyze the window content? based on its style  (assuming all dialogs have a similar style) | or u have some other idea?

Comment: Look at their titles, look at their child windows, looking for texts that are of interest to you.

Answer (score -1):

place the event into a try block and if the user does not have access it will fail and go to the catch block where you can use the exception which was generated to show the dialog box

Comment: Not what I intended- edited my question to be more precise

Comment: @shon what event do you refer to?

Comment: The original question was worded as such that it implied when the application is running.  A sidw note is that this can still ve ised and logged in a database to have a compiled list of the access denied and who it relates to

Comment: I was referring to os events